# How can I convert System.Byte[] to Image? (C# window forms)

Tags: c#

I have a `PictureBox` control I want to display an image in it. I saved my images in a MS Access database with this data type: `OLE Object`.
I find it hard to display it again. Please take a look at my code, and can you guys please devise a solution for it. I got this `Exception`:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.
```

Here's my code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT IMAGE FROM IMAGES WHERE ID = 1", myConn));
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt != null)
            {              
                pictureBox1.Image = (Image)dt.Rows[0]["IMAGE"];
            }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a `MemoryStream` and call `Image.FromStream`:

```
byte[] data = (byte[]) dt.Rows[0]["IMAGE"];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

EDIT: If you run up against the problem described by Hans, you basically need to strip out that header. Once you *have* got a byte array with just the image data in, use the above code.

Comment: But i dont fine PictureBox Option ?? please help

Comment: @Sanam: I don't know what you mean. In the context of the question, the OP has a pictureBox1 variable. I have no idea what you're trying to do or your context. I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Shouldn't we surround `MemoryStream` by `using` or at least dispose the instance after setting the control image?

Comment: @AlexJolig: You *mustn't* dispose of it - `Image.FromStream` assumes ownership of the stream. DIsposing of the image will dispose of the stream, but for a `MemoryStream` it doesn't matter anyway.