# Managing Images?

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I'm working on a class that will help me read a game file, and part of the file is an image. Is there an image object that I can create from a byte array, or should I just store the image as a byte array? If I were to put that image into a picture displayer in winforms, can I do that with a byte array?

What's the best way to store the data from the file?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the documentation on the `System.Drawing` namespace? What did you have problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440366/how-can-i-convert-system-byte-to-image-c-window-forms):

```
byte[] data = getYourImageData();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

to answer the other part of your question, it is fine to store it as a byte array - maybe provide a helper method that returns a memory stream as seen above, or alternatively store it in a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and return [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx):

```
return new Bitmap(ms);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Bitmap` class in `System.Drawing` supports a constructor that takes a stream as a parameter. This stream can be supplied by a `MemoryStream` that is created from a byte array.

Once you have the bitmap, a `PictureBox` can be used to display it.

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx (for the bitmap)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx (for the stream)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx (PictureBox)