# How to retrieve binary data image from sql server using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am developing a windows form application and I need to save and retrieve an image from an sql database. Actually I am storing the image values in a byte array but while I am retrieving data, I am not able to display the image. I have given my code below:

```
DataTable dtgetfeedback = Feedback.BOFeedBackRating.GetFeedBackratingcount(setFBRTID);

if (dtgetfeedback.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    gv_feedbackrating.DataSource = dtgetfeedback;
}
else
{
    gvdtgetdetail.Rows.Clear();
    DataRow drToAdd = gvdtgetdetail.NewRow();
    gvdtgetdetail.Rows.Add(drToAdd);
    gvdtgetdetail.AcceptChanges();
    gv_feedbackrating.DataSource = gvdtgetdetail;
}
```

Image values are stored bytearray

[image: Image values are stored bytearray]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert System.Byte\[\] to Image? (C# window forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440366/how-can-i-convert-system-byte-to-image-c-window-forms)

Comment: Not Duplicate question actually this is needed to show image on Gridview not a picturebox

Comment: you can have picturbox control on a gridview column

Comment: Actually, I had set picture edit repository in my grid column

Answer (score 1):

To show images based on byte arrays, assign [RepositoryItemPictureEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemPictureEdit.class) to the necessary column by setting the [GridColumn.ColumnEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.ColumnEdit.property) property. In addition, set the [RepositoryItemPictureEdit.PictureStoreMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemPictureEdit.PictureStoreMode.property) property to ByteArray.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this** - [Saving and loading binary images into a picture edit control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q488322/saving-and-loading-binary-images-into-a-picture-edit-control)

When you have stored images in byte array format then it should be byte array format during retrieval from the database. Then add Change the PictureEdit's [PictureStoreMode property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPictureEdit_PictureStoreModetopic) to ByteArray

```
PictureEdit1.Properties.PictureStoreMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureStoreMode.ByteArray;
```

> Related to view of image in the cells, By default, the
>   [RepositoryItemPictureEdit.SizeMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPictureEdit_SizeModetopic) is the
>   [PictureSizeMode.Clip](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q488322/PictureSizeMode) enumeration value of Clip. You may set the
>   PictureSizeMode.Squeeze value. You may also specify the picture
>   alignment at [RepositoryItemPictureEdit.PictureAlignment](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPictureEdit_PictureAlignmenttopic).

**References:**
[Bind a byte array to a PictureEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q218603/bind-a-byte-array-to-a-pictureedit)
[byte array column to image display](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q200983/byte-array-column-to-image-display)
[How to load a picture into the repositoryitemPictureEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q100485/how-to-load-a-picture-into-the-repositoryitempictureedit)
[ImageEdit binding](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q201238/imageedit-binding)

Comment: @Raj: If you have followed that way then it must work.. How are you saving data in database?? if data is correct everything should go fine

Comment: You are correct, I found my issue because when I was set image to gridview that byte image size was 924 something, but while I am saving to database byte image size was 24 something. I don't know why it was reducing

Comment: Are you using DXHelper methods to convert it to byte array or from byte array to image.. e.g. `DevExpress.XtraExport.ByteImageConverter.ToByteArray(im, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)`

Comment: Thank you for your support Niranjan. Just I need to know retrieve varbinary data from sql server. can u help me this thing. if you want tell tell me ill send my code

Comment: @just create an small sample and it would be much better to understand that it is really a issue with controls or something else..